# Debugging Android over WiFi without first authorizing over USB?

Tags: android

Essentially, my android phone's USB port is broken, so the only way to debug is over WiFi. Unfortunately, I hadn't authorized the device on my computer back when the USB was still working.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you are connected to the same network you can do the interface between mobile and your computer/PC by using IP Address.
Did I get you correctly?

Comment: Yep. The only problem is `adb devices` shows the device as being unauthorized.

Comment: Hi. I'm still facing the same issue. May I know if there is a solution for this?